# Is it possible to start a video file in a specific time in html4?

Tags: html

I want to play a video file (avi) at a specific time (for example, 40s) in html4. I found it's possible to manipulate a mp4 file in html5 using javascript. But apparently html5 doesn't cover avi file. It's quite a burden to convert all the avi files into mp4, as they are over 100. Are there any solutions?

Comment: HTML 5 provides APIs to manipulate video. HTML 4 provides none. So no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with HTML4 features, but there are other solutions...

HTML5 video is supported with a few video types - none of them .avi ->

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats`

Most web sites and applications that support HTML5 video have a flash player fallback. When the user's browser doesn't support HTML5 video, the flash player will play one of the encoded videos (.mp4 extension) through a .swf video player. Sites like Youtube use the query string from the URL to supply the video player with a start time in seconds. This video player will either be HTML5 or flash, but not HTML4. Avi videos aren't much use on web, so I'd recommend using **[Miro video encoder](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)** to encode avi's into mp4.